# How to make a portlet WSRP enabled?

Tags: java, portlet, wsrp

I have a liferay java portlet, I want to make it WSRP enabled. Is there any specific configuration files that I have to include apart from the tag true in liferay-portlet.xml

Any pointers would be helpful.

Thanks,Lokn

Answer (score 0):

Adding the tag to liferay-portlet.xml is only part of the solution. For everything to work correctly so your own portlet will be available remotely via WSRP you need to follow these instructions: [WSRP guide](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/WSRP).

This basically comes down to:

- Install the WSRP plugin
- Add producers
- Enable WSRP for custom portlets that you want to configure as a producer

Comment: thanks for the answer. We are planning to use the websphere to deploy the ear file, Is there any code changes that I have to do any additional config files that I need to add?

Comment: I've only installed Liferay on Tomcat, JBoss and Glassfish, so I can't really comment on that except to follow the WebSphere section in the installation guide as it has worked well for me for the other servers: http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/installing-liferay-on-an-existing-application-server